# Who are all the fences?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have unlocked a few fences along the way in the Thieves' Guild but I can't remember who they were or where they are. Does anyone have a comprehensive list of all the fences in Skyrim?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[**Tonilia**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Tonilia) becomes a fence after the quest [Taking Care of Business](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Taking_Care_of_Business). She can be found in [The Ragged Flagon](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Ragged_Flagon) in Riften.

[**Mallus Maccius**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mallus_Maccius) becomes a fence after the quest [Dampened Spirits](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dampened_Spirits) is completed. He can be found in the [Honningbrew Meadery](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Honningbrew_Meadery) near Whiterun.

[**Gulum-Ei**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Gulum-Ei) becomes a fence after the quest [Scoundrel's Folly](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Scoundrel%27s_Folly). He can be found in [The Winking Skeever](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Winking_Skeever) in Solitude.

[**Enthir**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Enthir) becomes a fence after the quest [Hard Answers](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hard_Answers). He can be found in [The Frozen Hearth](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Frozen_Hearth), in Winterhold.

[**Niranye**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Niranye) in Windhelm - owns a shop in the market just outside the white phial.  Becomes available after the quest [Summerset Shadows](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Summerset_Shadows).

There is a quest you do for Tonilia where you gain the allegiances of the Khajiit caravan that wanders Skyrim. Afterwards they will also act as a fence for you, although this is less usefull than those listed above as the caravan's location is constantly changing. The quest isn't showing in my list of completed quests so I'm assuming it's a miscellaneous quest.

Comment: This is my current list. I'm not through yet with the Thieve's Guild quest line so there might be more. Please feel free to edit this post and add more.

Comment: There are definitely more fences, the special requests that Delvin gives you unlocks 1 fence each.

Comment: @yx. ah indeed. I don't have much time right now but feel free to edit the answer if you like.

Answer (score 6):

[Endon](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Endon), in Markarth is also a fence.

Answer (score 5):

To add to the other answers, the UESP wiki has a list of all fences in the game in its [Thieves Guild](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_(faction)#Fences) article.

Other fences not yet mentioned by other answers are:

- **[Atahbah](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Atahbah)** - Roams Skyrim in a [Khajiit trading caravan](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Khajiit_Traders) with [Ri'saad](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ri%27saad), seen outside holds.
- **[Ma'jhad](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ma'jhad)** - Roams Skyrim in a Khajiit trading caravan with [Ma'dran](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ma%27dran), seen outside holds.
- **[Zaynabi](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Zaynabi)** - Roams Skyrim in a Khajiit trading caravan with [Ahkari](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ahkari), seen outside holds.

To acquire the services of the above fences, you must finish the [Thieves Guild Caravan Fence Quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_Caravan_Fence_Quest).